# What's the correct way to use a TypeVar with a parameterized bound?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I occasionally run into a scenario like the following:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class Widget(Generic[T]):
    content: T

class Jibbit(Generic[T]):
    element: T

class ThingHolder:
    thing: Widget | Jibbit
```

In the Python standard library, this situation arises in [`logging.handlers.QueueListener`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/logging/handlers.pyi#L256-L266), where the `QueueListener.queue` attribute is equivalent to `ThingHolder.thing` above.

Now I want to convert `ThingHolder` so that it is parameterized by the type of the `thing` that it holds, so that I can differentiate between, for example, `ThingHolder[Widget[int]]` and `ThingHolder[Jibbit[int]]`.

How do you spell this correctly with a `TypeVar`? If I write

```py
Thing = TypeVar('Thing', bound=Widget | Jibbit)
```

then I get an error because I didn't specify a parameter for the two parameterized types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're supposed to parameterize the types in the `bound=` itself, and not attempt to parameterize the new type variable:

```py
Thing = TypeVar('Thing', bound=Widget[Any] | Jibbit[Any])


class ThingHolder(Generic[Thing]):
    thing: Thing

    def __init__(self, thing: Thing) -> None:
        self.thing = thing
```

I originally thought that this wouldn't work, because the "inner" type parameter isn't written anywhere in the definition. But it does in fact work:

```py
# OK
w_int: Widget[int] = Widget(1)
th_w_int: ThingHolder[Widget[int]] = ThingHolder(w_int)

# OK
w_str: Widget[str] = Widget("hello")
th_w_str: ThingHolder[Widget[str]] = ThingHolder(w_str)

# Errors!
th_w_str = ThingHolder(w_int)
th_w_int = ThingHolder(w_str)

reveal_type(ThingHolder(Jibbit(None)))
# __main__.ThingHolder[__main__.Jibbit[None]]

reveal_type(ThingHolder(Jibbit([1,2,3])))
# __main__.ThingHolder[__main__.Jibbit[builtins.list[builtins.int]]]
```

I *think* it works because something like `Widget[int]` is indeed a subtype of `Widget[Any] | Jibbit[Any]`, while something like `list[int]` is not. Clearly, Mypy is smart enough to track the "inner" types, even when they are not explicitly written in the class definition. Moreover, if you had the opportunity to inject your own type variable in the inner parameter, you might accidentally mess it up by using the wrong type variance for the inner parameter.